# Is this graph with $n$ vertices a planar graph?

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $G$ be a graph with vertices $2,...,n+1$ such that every vertex is connected to the vertex which is the number of its divisors. How can we prove that such a graph is planar? Also, does such a graph have a name?

Comment: I would have thought you could show this was a tree (with a loop for $2$)

Comment: Or you can just use an induction argument

Comment: It can be handy to use notation $\tau(n)$ for the sum of divisors (see [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Combinatorics_and_Discrete_Mathematics/Elementary_Number_Theory_(Raji)/))

Comment: @JeanMarie Please explain as I did no such thing.

Comment: Sorry, I made a confusion : I thought you hadn't written that you were beginning ar $2$

Comment: Following the idea of @Henry : in this graph the vertex associated with $n+1$ is of degree $1$ so it should be a trivial proof?

Answer (score 1):

When n is large enough, we have vertices 2,4,8,16,32 whose spanning graph is a copy of clique of size 5, so G does not be planar.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I see you want to apply Kuratowski theorem (it would be better to give the name), but I don't understand your answer. How these powers of 2 give a clique ? Look attentively the text : A vertex is connected to the vertex "number of divisors"...

Comment: Yes, this is my fault. But I think that this question is trivial, as every number has at most number  of itself of its divisors so that this graph is acyclic.(otherwise the largest number of this cycle has degree at least 2, this is contradictory with the consequence above.)

Comment: @zhiyin I would agree with your comment "this question is trivial, as every number has at most number of itself of its divisors so that this graph is acyclic" (in fact, apart from $2$, each number has strictly fewer divisors).  But your answer seems to be saying the opposite